# Spring boot conectar dinámicamente con un número indeterminado de DataSources

Tags: base-de-datos, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, schema

Tengo un proyecto con una base de datos MySQL (bd principal) que tengo que mantener sincronizada con otras N bases de datos (también MySQL). Cada una de estas otras bases de datos se corresponde con una empresa diferente.

En la bd principal, tengo una entidad Company con una serie de atributos que he de sincronizar y otro atributo llamado "schema" que indica el nombre de la base de datos externa que contiene información acerca de esa company en concreto, que es a la que me debo conectar.

De este modo, voy a crear una rutina que se ejecutará cada X tiempo y que debe recorrer la lista de companies en la bd principal. Por cada company que encuentre, mirará el atributo *"schema"* y si por ejemplo es *"librosGarcia"* la aplicación deberá conectarse a:

**jdbc:mysql://servidor:puerto/librosGarcia**

He buscado tutoriales sobre cómo hacer esto, pero en todos los ejemplos que encuentro se crea un apartado en el application.yml para cada datasource. En mi caso concreto, podría haber un datasource común para todas las bds externas, porque *"servidor:puerto"*, así como *"username"*, *"password"* y *"driver-class-name"* no cambiará, pero *"librosGarcia"* será diferente en cada caso.

Es esto posible? Agradecería cualquier ayuda.